Dans la phrase «Mes yeux ne voyaient plus, je ne pouvais parler ;» quel est le procédé ?
Dans l'acte 1 scène 3 de la pièce de théâtre de Phèdre cette phrase est mentionnée .. quel est le type de procédé utilisé ? parce que je fais un commentaire et j'ai besoin de créer le type de procédé

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Surely you asked Google about this sentence? What did it answer?

Il y a, je pense, une asyndète utilisée à des fins de parallélisme : la conjonction "et" qui devrait relier les deux propositions est ici omise, ce qui les juxtapose et fait apparaître leur similitude de construction.
